# AWS Cognito oauth2/token posting the data error (Unauthorized client error)

Tags: python, flask, amazon-cognito

I am using hosted UI for login in AWS Cognito,

```
@app.route('/callback')  
def callback():
    code = str(request.args.get('code'))
    client_id = "***********************"
    client_secret = "**************************************"
    redirect_uri = f"http://localhost:5000/upload"  # Update with your actual redirect URI

    # Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    token_url = f"https://***domain****.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token"
    data = {
        'grant_type': "authorization_code",
        'code': code,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri
    }
    data=dict(data)

    print(data)
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
    print(response.json())
    if response.status_code == 200:
        token_data = response.json()
        access_token = token_data['access_token']
        print(access_token)
        return redirect('http://localhost:5000/upload')
    else:
        return 'Access Token retrieval failed'
```

[Access token retrieval failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Fcx.png)

and I am getting `400 error {'error': 'unauthorized_client'}` error in the console
but I made sure that the client id and client secret key are correct and also listed all the necessary endpoints in the cognito redirect uri.

Domain string: `f'https://******.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=**********&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/callback'`

for the same client and secret key but with the endpoint as `https://www.google.co.in/` in Postman (when I entered the code in uri manually into postman), I got all the tokens as output with the proper code in uri